# Training material for JavaScript/JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Does anyone know about a good tutorial/article/whatever to help me explain JavaScript ( with emphasis in JSON ) ?

I want to teach to the new team members what is JSON and how to apply it effectively, but instead of trying to re-invent the wheel ( and probably doing it wrong ) I'm looking for some training material, article, talk or whatever it is appropriate, to teach them ( and improve my knowledge  in the process ) good JavaScript practices, pitfalls, etc, in order to take the best from the language.

We are about to start using Ext and of course we will use JSON as interchange protocol.

Comment: JSON != JavaScript. It is a *tiny* data serialization format that happens to be identical to a very tiny subset of JavaScript. What are you actually looking for? "JSON and how to parse and/or generate it using JavaScript" perhaps?

Comment: @David, funny, I was told, that JSON == Javascript  :-/ What I'm looking for is how to explain correct terminology,  ( for instance { } is an object literal and not just braces ) difference with a Object Oriented language such as Java,  best practices, etc. etc.  We all know ( in my company ) a bit of "empirical" Javascript, I'm looking for some training material to fill the gap and/or correct misconceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start here - http://www.json.org/

Also, "google" around for Douglas Crockford -

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/ (good videos on here)

Comment: +1 from who would you learn JSON if not the inventor of JSON? :)

Comment: +1 for the link, I think I could make a summary very useful from those videos.